# Blazor WASM bypass authorization checks

Tags: .net, authorization, blazor-webassembly

**Introduction**

Microsoft states in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization) not to use the Blazor client for authorization.

> In Blazor WebAssembly apps, authorization checks can be bypassed because all client-side code can be modified by users. The same is true for all client-side app technologies, including JavaScript SPA frameworks or native apps for any operating system.
> Always perform authorization checks on the server within any API endpoints accessed by your client-side app.

The way I understand it, the claims of an access token are merely a non-binding information for the Blazor client, so that the correct information is shown. Users could still view content protected by `<AuthorizeView Policy="IsSomebodySpecial">`, even if they don't have the necessary claims for that policy in their access token.

**Problem Statement**

The burden of proof is on my side now to prevent a design that relies on the client for authorization, while the accessed API has no authorization.

**Question**

How can one bypass the authorization check in the browser to demonstrate the security risk?